# Redis update all scores in sorted set

Tags: redis

I  have sorted set with scores like this

```
score | value
   20 | val1
   18 | val2
   16 | val3
```

I need to divide each score by 100 and get the following result

```
score | value
  0.2 | val1
 0.18 | val2
 0.16 | val3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis can do that by way of the `Z*STORE` commands, albeit [scores are stored as double 64-bit floating point numbers](https://redis.io/commands/ZADD#range-of-integer-scores-that-can-be-expressed-precisely) and are subject to floating point arithmetic issues and limitations.

Here is how to derive a new sorted set with a 1/100th of the scores of another set using the [`ZUNIONSTORE` command](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) along with the `WEIGHTS` option, which allows to specify a multiplication factor:

```
ZADD source 20 val1
ZADD source 18 val2
ZADD source 16 val3

ZUNIONSTORE target 1 source WEIGHTS 0.01
```

It is also possible to overwrite the original sorted set by passing it as both the source and target key, if needed:

```
ZUNIONSTORE source 1 source WEIGHTS 0.01
```

Comment: My pleasure, @Alex :)